# How to resolve and/or answer outdated questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

There are many unanswered questions relating to pre-launch dawn-era code. Should these questions be answered in the context of the question or answered with updated information referencing the current code?

I don't think these questions should be left lingering in the beta phase of the site.

Should they be closed or answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read through some other meta threads about related issues.

My conclusion is that these questions **should be answered if they are still relevant and it is possible to answer them**. This maybe the case if somebody may be actively developing for a prior release-version (after June 2018).

All before that or questions with low quality can be **marked as "off-topic" and closed**, because the code is outdated and may not be stable. If needed we can still reopen the questions.

**Deletion is no option**, because of dead links and lost content.